# Can not compile shaders with Linux/Mesa

Tags: linux, opengl, glsl, opengl-3, mesa

I have a OpenGL 3.0 application which works well when it is used with Windows. My shader programs all start with

```
#version 130 core\n
```

Now when I stwich over to linux with OpenGL 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5, compiling of these shaders fails with error message

```
Vertex shader failed: 0:1(10): error: illegal text following version number
```

What could be the problem here? It is definitely OpenGL 3.0 which should support GLSL 1.3 - what illegal text is it complaining about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> #version 130 core
> ```

This version number simply *does not exist*. OpenGL profiles like *core* and *compatibility* were introduced in OpenGL 3.2, together with GLSL 1.50.

The correct version directive for [GLSL 1.30](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf) (from OpenGL 3.0) is just

```
#version 130
```

see section "3.3 Preprocessor" of the [GLSL 1.30 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf):

> Shaders should declare the version of the language they are written to. The language version a shader is
>   written to is specified by
>
> ```
> #version number
> ```
>
> where number must be a version of the language, following the same convention as `__VERSION__` above.
>   The directive `#version 130` is required in any shader that uses version 1.30 of the language. Any
>   number representing a version of the language a compiler does not support will cause an error to be
>   generated.